# Why don't sandwich toasters have an on/off switch?

Tags: physical

The absolute majority of electrical appliances have an On/Off switch. However, the absolute majority of sandwich toasters do not - you just plug them into the socket and unplug them when you're done. At least, that's the case for all household sandwich toasters I've ever seen. I'm referring to this device, not the vertical toaster (where the lever doubles as a switch):

[image]

It looks like some models do have a switch, but apparently these are just the larger/industrial types, not the common variety.

Why is that?

Comment: Doesn't the lid serve that dual purpose?

Comment: @MarjanVenema If it does, then I don't know about it :).

Comment: Hmm, and checking could be a burning experience... :-)

Comment: A more intense debate of the electrical aspects of this along with a similar Q&A can be found here: [Where is the switch?](http://ask.metafilter.com/83190/Where-is-the-switch)

Comment: The Tefal model has a switch and also plates that can be taken out to wash.

Comment: I for one, think this is incredibly bad design.  I have read all the answers below and have arrived at this page because people in my office are continually leaving the sandwich toaster on over night.  Three times in 5 days.  With today's lighter touch technologies, I think pulling the chord out seems like overkill to some people ... plus, their focus is getting their very hot sandwich out of the toaster safely, the situation is ripe with distraction!

Comment: Do sandwich toasters still not have on/off switches?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When designing one of the first thing you learn is **safety first**. On a device generating heat, having a power button which could easily be forgotten, is a bad idea. In this particular case, the consequences can be severe if a user forgets to power off. That is why the power button has been deliberately omitted. Cognitively speaking, it is easier to remember to pull the cord from the jack than switching off a button. You use more muscles and are often forced to use both hands. Using more of your body in an action helps you to remember. The case is the same with an iron.

[image]

<sup>Iron without power button</sup>

This is the reason for not having a power button on non-exclusive heat generating devices. But, there are differences. Exclusive hardware having electronics for safety do have a power button, since it saves the user from error. As in the [Sandwich Toaster by taerv](http://www.taerv.com/?p=136):

> This sandwich toaster is designed for people who seek high quality and durable home appliances. Thanks to power button there is no need for pluging cable to the socket every time we want to use this device,
>   and built-in a timer makes it much easier to use. While using you do not have to check the state of the thing we toast – you only have to set amount time you want (shown by shining diodes), after which the sandwich toaster turns itself off and signals that with a sound.
>
> Straight handle and special hinge facilitates compressing thicker sandwiches and steel latch will never break. Heating plates are interchangeable so the device is much more functional and it’s easier to keep it clean.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the iron analogue. And I just have an idea of adding an accelerometer to iron so it may be automatically turned off if it's not used for a specific amount of time.

Comment: @alexeypegov Thanks! You accelerometer sounds like a great idea, and good **safety first** thinking!

Comment: Great idea @BennySkogberg

Comment: No power-off button on a sandwich toaster can still cause accidents though. 'Hypothetically speaking' someone *could* make them-self a Tuna Toastie while watching a horror movie late at night but forget to unplug the toaster; causing the toaster to short-circuit, blow the trip switch in the fuse box (causing all the lights and electrics in the house to shut down too, which could be quite scary at the best of times but *especially* during a late night horror movie) and also result in the toaster breaking forever. Hypothetically speaking of course.

Comment: @JonW I agree that this is not bullit proof - but its better than a power button. You could also use an external timer on the jack, which I use on my Nespresso machine at home, or buy the expensive toaster with built in safety. The Nespresso machine goes into "hybernating" state if we're not using it - but an external timer feel better. Safety costs!

Comment: @alexeypegov: Not a new idea; my iron already has precisely that. Beeps in 5 and turns off in 8 minutes.

Comment: I am even more skeptical than @JonW. If this really is the reason, then why am I not forced to unplug my oven/stove each time? Or to turn off the gas on my gas stove? A stove left on is likely causing a fire somewhere *right now as we speak*. And so do irons, by the way. People *constantly* leave them on. Just because you have to unplug, doesn't mean you will. So that's two reasons right there why this is just hypothetical conjecture. For all we know, the companies really just want to save a couple cents on switches. As you say yourself, more expensive models do have a switch.

Comment: @RegDwight your oven is insulated (though your stove is not), which does prevent at least *some* fires. With a stove it would be harder to put on a timer - frequently you put something on to boil and walk away. Or doing something that takes a long/unknown amount of time to cook. But... you may be right to be skeptical!

Comment: @Wayne yes, this is all justification in hindsight. If it were exactly the other way round, we'd just as easily be able to come up with a bunch of just as sound reasons for it being exactly the other way round. Nobody, ever, is willing to say "There is no reason" or "Even if there is a reason, I do not know it. So I am making this up."

Comment: @RegDwight Nobody, ever, is willing to say "There is no reason" or "Even if there is a reason, I do not know it. So I am making this up." - welcome to UX :)

Comment: A bread toaster has the best design: turning the power off is built into the physical cycle of making the toast.

Comment: @WayneWerner says: "*With a stove it would be harder to put on a timer*". Technology changes though. We just bought a new gas range, and it automatically shuts off the oven after, I think, 4 hours. (This feature *can* be overridden by setting "Sabbath mode", but that affects other things that make it annoying enough one wouldn't normally leave it in that mode.) Oh, and when it *does* automatically turn off, it sends an alert to the app on my mobile device.  As I said, technology changes.

Answer (score 20):

First of all, as you mentioned, today many of these do have a on\off button.

If I had to guess, I would say that a reason to not having a button is that the electricity cable is the most explicit and obvious state indicator - If it's in the wall, it's on, otherwise it's off.

Since these toasters should not be left on, being both dangerous and costly, the makers may have decided to make the decision simple and be explicit about it.
If you go in the kitchen and see it plugged in, it's on...

Just my intuition.

Comment: Really good point. Also, it could be based on the idea that a toaster is not something you need to be plugged in all day. It's a device you use for maybe 10 minutes a day, and it often shares a power socket with other devices such as the coffee machine (just like a mixer does for example). It may be an invalid idea, but it's possible that manufacturers never thought of the idea that people would want to keep it plugged in the whole time.

Comment: I haven't encountered one with a button that's meant for home use. The electricity cable is a good indicator for all electrical appliances, but still most of them do have a button :). Why should the toaster be any different?

Comment: If that is indeed a usability fault with no better reasons than historical ones, I guess whoever introduces a home sandwich toaster with an on/off switch would disrupt the market

Comment: Having a switch in a toaster is a safety failure...

Comment: @vitaly didn't you eventually mark the correct answer that says the same thing my answer did?

Comment: @Ben Not quite. Your answer says that it's because the cable is the most explicit indicator. This is equally true for all other electrical appliances and yet they all have buttons. Benny's answer explains how a toaster is different from other appliances and provides convincing reasoning for the lack of the button.

Answer (score 6):

I totally agree that it is a safety precaution. It is a very clear indicator that something is on without an On / Off button if you see the plug in the wall.

Let's also not forget that if the cord and plug is essentially the means of turning it on / off it will get a lot of use. The Breville Panini Press I have at home has a clever plug with a finger hole that 1) Makes it very easy to remove from the wall 2) Eliminates the desire to just tug on the cord to remove the plug (never do this!) and weakening the attachment of the wire to the plug

[image]

Comment: But... how does the electricity get through the hole?? ;)

Comment: I believe it uses your finger as the conductive element to complete the circuit... I could be wrong though :)

Comment: Clever plug! really like it. I need one of these for my smartphone charger...

Comment: This plug makes me somewhat uncomfortable...

Answer (score 4):

I think the primary reason is convenience. The lifting of the lid serves as a visual indicator of how much the sandwich is done and also also deactivates the heating coil. If a person wants to grill it anymore he has to just close it again and open it when he think its grilled sufficiently. Having a switch makes a two step process i.e
  1. Switch off to turn off the heating coil
  2. Open the lid

Hence then turning it back on again becomes a two step process i.e. closing it and then turning it on (and there is a good reason people might forget about turning it on and come back after a few minutes and find the sandwich is still cold)

The other reason I think is safety. If someone opens the sandwich maker without shutting it down and touches the heating appliance, it might not be a pleasant situation but the additional action of the heating coil switching off when opened prevents the possibility of that happen (I know there are chances of burns due to hot coils and so on but thats something I have no answer for).

Answer (score 2):

Cost. If the manufacturer can save $.25 by not putting a switch on it, that's extra profit. I believe they can justify it by assuming that these aren't devices people would typically leave on their counter. They take them out, plug them in, use it, then clean and store it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a safety precaution. Making a sandwich creates a lot of mess -- the butter and cheese normally get stuck to the grill plates after use. If there was an off switch, people may be tempted to leave the device plugged in before placing their **dripping-wet dish cloth** onto the grill plates. In general, these types of devices are not watertight and if a little bit of water gets into the 'inner workings', the user could be in for a nasty shock.

No sensible person would consider cleaning while the grill plates were still hot. This forces them to unplug the device from the mains, thus reducing the risk of electrocution. (I recently electrocuted myself refilling a mains connected iron.)

Comment: electrocuted: you keep using that word, i do not think it means what you think it means

Answer (score 0):

Besides of the security reasons, there is no need to keep a sandwich inside when it is off. When it's empty, for the security reasons, it's better to plug it off than switch it off using a switch, and no switch mostly forces users to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Cost could be the only factor. What is the safety gains from having an electric item that cooks food not switch itself off? You put the sandwich in the sandwich toaster, then go off to your bedroom and play computer games and completely forget about the sandwich you are toasting. What happens? Surely the dangers of that outweigh the ability to remind someone to switch the toaster off at the powerpoint.

When I was young actual toasters did not switch automatically either. Whew. The dangers in that. Fortunately, they invented automatic ones in about 1970 or so. When are they going to do the same for sandwich toasters? It is ridiculous that they don't.

Answer (score -1):

Cost could be a factor, but that could mean that a competitor could put in a switch to make his product attractive.
I think one main reason could be sound.Heating devices,like irons etc can be hazardous if left on, and we wouldn't know they are on. Ever wonder why a hair dryer or a fan has a button? Sound! :)